# arcpy Toolbox GPExtent default values

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, python-toolbox

can anybody help me with setting a default value for a python toolbox parameter:

```
param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Exportgebiet",
            name="in_area_set",
            datatype="GPExtent",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
```

What I want to do ist set the default value to the extent of the currently loaded map document.

I tried

```
    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    ...
      mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
      parameters[1].value = mxd.activeDataFrame.extent
    ...
```

but it did not work.

The dropdown box for the parameter should be "As Specified Below" or "Same as Display".

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?